# How to use if statements in templates templates.jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What is problem in this code... I've tried a lot of solutions, but always error in the if loop ..

```
<script type="text/template" id="tableItemPageView">

<% if(%>${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name } === <@= table.user @><%){  %>

<td><@= table.id @></td>                
            <td><@= table.name @></td>
            <td><@= table.changed @></td>
            <td><@= table.description @></td>
            <td class="correctUser"><a href="#tables/edit/<@=table.id@>">Edit </a><a  
                   href="#tables/show/<@=table.id@>"> Players</a><a id="removeTable">  Delete</a>       

<% }else{  %>

<td><@= table.id @></td>                
            <td><@= table.name @></td>
            <td><@= table.changed @></td>
            <td><@= table.description @></td>
<% } %>
</script>
```

On this solution I have one error , after "if" have error "Syntax error on token "(", Expression expected after this token".

I want to check is it the registered user the same as the user who created the
table...

Comment: why dont use `<c:if>` tag?

Comment: what is `table.user` here?

Comment: I also use a backbone.js, I define the templete "<script type="text/javascript">
  _.templateSettings = {
   interpolate : /\<\@\=(.+?)\@\>/gim,
   evaluate : /\<\@(.+?)\@\>/gim,
   escape : /\<\@\-(.+?)\@\>/gim
  };
 </script>" and can' use <c:if>

Comment: table.user is user who created table . If registered user the same as the user who created the table I wont show row where is button from edit and delete table , if registered user is not same with table.user then show without that row. I also have annotations in the controler class for who can edit and delete table

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Use [**Implicit object**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnaij/index.html) that are available in JSP to access any attribute from any scope.

Use `if` core tag library

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.userPrincipal.name == ’XYZ’}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

OR use `when/otherwise` core tag library that is equivalent to JAVA switch statement

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${requestScope.userPrincipal.name == ’XYZ’}" >
         ...
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
         ...
     </c:otherwise>
 </c:choose>
```

Comment: I try and now have this exception ... "org.apache.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered " <ILLEGAL_CHARACTER> "\u0080 "" at line 1, column 39.
Was expecting one of:
    "}" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ..." I think I can't use this tags becose is templates and I have this part of code ..."<script type="text/javascript">
  _.templateSettings = {
   interpolate : /\<\@\=(.+?)\@\>/gim,
   evaluate : /\<\@(.+?)\@\>/gim,
   escape : /\<\@\-(.+?)\@\>/gim
  };
 </script>"

Comment: In the end its a JSP. read mor about JSTL or EL and tag library

Comment: I'll definitely read it , and try to solve with that. Thanks for the advice, definitely will be useful to read...

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

Replace

```
<@= table.user @>
```

with

```
<%= table.user %>
```

Comment: I think you're right, I changed, and I don't have a mistake in the first line the loop, but in the last line ,in this part "<% } %>" I have this error  "Syntax error on token ";", delete this token"

Comment: Are you sure about === operator ?

Comment: A guess,  == operator is not in any jsp tag,

Comment: You closed jsp tag before the == operator